# Encoding issue, from html form data, to python print

Tags: python-3.x, encoding

I'm getting in Python 3 the data from an HTML form. To simplify to the maximum, my Python code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
print('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n')

data = form.getvalue('nom')

print(data)
```

Now it prints (like it's supposed to) the name filled in the HTML form, however when that name has an accent (for example Valérie), then the accented character is printed as a ? (in this case Python prints Val?rie).

I know it's a problem of encoding (Python being notorious for this), and I've searched quite a bit (encode, decode, locale, etc...) but didn't get it to work unfortunately. If anyone knows how to fix this and have it print Valérie, I'd really appreciate it ;-)

EDIT: got it to work using print(data.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1'))
Take care.

Comment: Try it with adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of you file. If it does not work, encode the values you want to get with [python endcode()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_encode.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had already tried the # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- at the top, but it hadn't solved anything, as I understand UTF-8 is the defaut in Python 3 anyway.I tried again the encode() function, and if I pass the name Valérie and do data.encode('utf-8'), it then prints b'Val\xc3\xa9rie'

Comment: Would it be an option to encode the inputfield?